# Where does eclipse look for binary libraries in plugins?

Tags: java, linux, macos, eclipse-plugin, dynamic-library

I have an eclipse plugin (developed by a third party, no source code available) that uses a binary library to do some of its work.  The library is open source.  The distributed plugin includes only the binary for Windows, but I can easily compile it for other platforms.  What I can't figure out is where to *put* the library so that it will be picked up.  I'm currently working on OS X, but Linux is an issue as well.

The Windows library is placed in eclipse/plugins/plugin_name/os/win32/x86.  I've tried using os/macosx/x86_64 (which corresponds to the the constants in org.eclipse.osgi.service.environments) and a bunch of other variants but nothing works, and I can't find any documentation on how eclipse sets the library path.

Where should I put libraries in a plugin sub-directory so that eclipse will load them for the appropriate platform?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to re-compile the library binary **and** recompile the JNI link between their java native methods an JNI C/C++?

Answer (score 1):

Binary libraries (*.dll for example) can be bundled within the plugin JAR itself. In this case it is probably in /os/win32/x86/thelib.dll.

If you can edit the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF in the thirdparty plugin (unzip the jar file), check for the header "Bundle-NativeCode". For example:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: /os/win32/x86;osname=win32;processor=x86
```

Then you could add paths for OS X this way:

```
Bundle-NativeCode: /os/win32/x86;osname=win32;processor=x86, /os/osx/x86; osname=macosx;processor=x86
```

Place OS X libs in the corresponding folder, rezip the jar and you should be done!